# Android Espresso: How can I type text into a editText embedded in a TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-espresso, textinputlayout

Looking for a way to replaceText or typeText into a edit text embedded in a TextInputLayout.

I have tried a few things like this:

```
perform(ViewActions.typeTextIntoFocusedView("String"));
```

but I always end up with this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
(((is displayed on the screen to the user) and has focus on the screen to the user) and (supports input methods or is assignable from class: class android.widget.SearchView))
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create a new `ViewAction` since Espresso doesn't have access to the `EditText` embedded inside the `TextInputLayout`. You can use something like this

```
class TextInputLayoutActions {
    class ReplaceTextAction(private val text: String): ViewAction {
        override fun getDescription(): String {
            return String.format(Locale.ROOT, "replace text(%s)", text)
        }

        override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> {
            return allOf(isDisplayed(), ViewMatchers.isAssignableFrom(TextInputLayout::class.java))
        }

        override fun perform(uiController: UiController?, view: View?) {
            (view as? TextInputLayout?)?.let {
                it.editText?.setText(text)
            }
        }

    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun replaceText(text: String): ViewAction {
            return actionWithAssertions(ReplaceTextAction(text))
        }
    }
}
```

and then use it like

```
<ViewInteraction>.perform(TextInputLayoutActions.replaceText(<text>)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it this way If you have access to the activity you can use findviewById as well

```
 @Test
fun testSave() {
    val book = Book(
        title = "Machine Learning",
        author = "Mohammed Fahim khan",
        year = "2021", imageUrl = ""
    )
    val testViewModel = BookViewModel(FakeBookRepositoryIT())
    launchFragmentInHiltContainer<BookDetailsFragment>(factory = fragmentFactory) {
        viewModel = testViewModel
        binding.etTitle.editText?.setText(book?.title.toString())
        binding.etName.editText?.setText(book?.author.toString())
        binding.etYear.editText?.setText(book?.year.toString())

    }


    /*onView(withId(R.id.et_title)).perform(replaceText(book.title))
    onView(withId(R.id.et_name)).perform(replaceText(book.author))
    onView(withId(R.id.et_year)).perform(replaceText(book.year))*/
    onView(withId(R.id.btn_save)).perform(click())
    val list = testViewModel.bookList.getOrAwaitValue()
    assertThat(list).contains(book)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as:

```
onView(withId(R.id.YOUR_INPUT)).perform(typeText("bla bla"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am a few years late to this question, and I can't tell you what way is best, but the answers put forth so far seem over complicated to me.

In my own tests, I am successfully putting values into a `TextInputEditText` embedded in a `TextInputLayout` by identifying the parent `TextInputLayout` and then finding the descendant view that has a class ending with "EditText" which should cover `EditText` or `TextInputEditText`.

```
onView(allOf(
    isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.tilTicketNum)),
    withClassName(endsWith("EditText")))
).perform(scrollTo(), replaceText("123456"));
```

You may have trouble with this approach if you add more than one child view to your `TextInputLayout`, but I'm pretty sure that goes against material design standards so I don't think it should be an issue in most cases.

*For reference, I am currently using:*

- *androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.0-alpha03*
- *org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3*